# How to display Just D, I, E, F instead of DEBUG, INFO, ERRO, FATAL in log4j

Tags: log4j

We are trying to optimize the size of files generated by log4j2. So I was thinking if we can reduce the number of characters that get printed on the final `.log` file. Below is the current pattern layout

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %p [%F] %m%n
```

Which generates the below logs

```
07:37:31,416 DEBUG [FileUtils.java] bla bla bla
```

What I want is the below to get displayed instead

```
07:37:31,416 D [FileUtils.java] bla bla bla
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the log4j documentation: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout

It mentions two ways to achieve your desired output. Include one of the following strings in you pattern configuration instead of the `%p`:

```
%level{WARN=W, DEBUG=D, ERROR=E, TRACE=T, INFO=I}
%level{length=1}
```

The first one will map the levels explicitly, while the second will cut the label length to 1. Either one will work. Note, that `%p` is just short-hand notation for `%level`.

Your full configuration property will look as follow using the second option with the abbreviation `%p` instead of `%level`:

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %p{length=1} [%F] %m%n
```

Comment: is this also possible in log4j itself?

Comment: This is taken straight from the log4j2 documentation. It does not require additional dependencies. I can imagine that it would also work with log4j 1.x versions. You would need to try it out, if you are using such an old version.

Comment: it didnt work with log4j1.x so asked. anyways we will upgrade to log4j2